# Confused about summing over the velocity squared term

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, kinematics, pressure, ideal-gas

> Consider a cubical box, L on each side. The box contains N molecules of ideal gas, each of mass m.
>
> All collisions are elastic. The force exerted by one molecule when it collides with a wall of the box that is perpendicular to the x-axis is, from the impulse equation: 
>   $$F = \frac{2mv_x}{Δt} \tag{1}$$ 
>   Our single molecule collides with this wall once every: 
>   $$Δt = \frac{2L}{v_x} \tag{2}$$ 
>   This gives an average force of: 
>   $$F = \frac{mv_x^2}{L} \tag{3}$$ 
>   This is the force from a single molecule. The total force on the wall is the sum over all the molecules: 
>   $$\Sigma F = \frac{Σmv_x^2}{L} = \frac{mN}{L} \left[\frac{Σv_x^2}{N}\right ] \tag{4}$$
>
> The term in square brackets represents the average value of $v_x^2$. The square root of this average is known as the root-mean-square (rms) average of $v_x$, so: 
>   $$\Sigma F = \frac{mN}{L} v_{x rms}^2 \tag{5}$$
>   By symmetry, all directions in the box are equivalent, so: 
>   $$ v^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 = 3v_x^2 \tag{6}$$ 
>   This gives: 
>   $$\Sigma F = \frac{mN}{3L} v_{rms}^2 \tag{7}$$ 
>   Dividing by the area, $L^2$, of the wall gives the pressure: 
>   $$P = \frac{mN}{3L^3} v_{rms}^2 \tag{8}$$
>   which is: 
>   $$PV = \frac{N}{3} \left[mv_{rms}^2\right] = \frac{2N}{3} \left[½ mv_{rms}^2\right] $$
>   The term in square brackets is $K_av$, the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules in the box. 
>   Therefore $$PV = \frac{2N}{3} K_{av}  $$

*Why is only $v_x^2$ being summed over in $(4)$ if it is the total force? Why not $$ \sum_{i} m_i (v_x^2)_i \tag?$$

Comment: The second quotes sentence says “of mass m” not $m_i$. They’re all the same.